# How to configure an email client?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I want to setup my Thunderbird email client. But the problem is that I want to use SMTP server provided by my ISP and I want my POP3 as the server on which my company has hosted their mail server.

I am really confused about what email id should go in what field, what password should go in what field. So the details are as follows:

smtp_server: smtp.bsnl.in
smtp_password: smtppass

pop3_server: pop3.xam.co.uk
pop3_password: poppass

I have my company mail id as

**abc@trex.com**

To access my company mail id, I need to open a webpage

**www.xyz.com**

There, I need to give a username which is

**trex.com_abc**

The password I gave there is **trexpass**

So can you please tell me how to configure the mail client (thunderbird desired).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the 'create a new account' dialog. There is 'email account' selected by default, click Next. Enter your name and email address (abc@trex.com) in provided fields, click Next. POP method is selected by default, enter POP3 server name (pop3.xam.co.uk) in the field, enter SMTP server name (smtp.bsnl.in), click Next. Enter your POP3 username ('abc' probably) in field, leave default user name for provider's SMTP server (if he does not restrict you to some specific username), click Next. Enter whatever you want in Account Name field, click Next and then Finish. The account is configured.

POP3 and SMTP passwords will be prompted at first message retrieving and sending, accordingly.